# Why does setProperty in Java return Object?

Tags: java

The Properies class in Java SE 6 has a method called `setProperty(String key, String value)`, which returns an `Object`. Furthermore, the previous `Object` stored for this key, or `NULL` if none exists.
Since `setProperty(String key, String value)` can only take a `String` as value, why doesn't that method return a `String`?

Comment: if you look at the javadoc you'll find out that it just returns the value you are setting.

Comment: Because it is a badly disguised HashMap?

Comment: This steProperty has been around from 1.2: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: @JuanAlbertoLópezCavallotti - My Javadoc says it returns the result of `HashTable.put()` which would be the *previous* value, or null if there wasn't one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately class `java.util.Properties` was introduced into java 1.0, many years before generics. `Properties` extends `Hashtable` that can store any type of data. So, you can do the following:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("key", new Object());  // use Hashtable's put method
props.setProperty("key", "value"); // use Proerties' setProperty method
```

In this example `setProperty` must return the previous value stored in this entry, i.e. `Object`. But it is not `String`! To avoid `ClassCastException` the JDK creators had to define `setProperty()` as method that returns `Object`.

BTW even now class Properties implements `Map<Object, Object>` instead of `Map<String, String>` for backwards compatibility.

Comment: But why `getProperty` returns `String` instead of `Object`？

Answer (score 13):

Because Properties was misconceived from the start by extending Hashtable, which can store anything. The design thus didn't respect the Liskov substitution principle: everything a base class can do, a subclass must be able to do.

Since Properties extends Hashtable, you can in fact store any kind of Object in it.